# Jquery find() not working with two ids one having the substring of the other

Tags: jquery, find, undefined

I have HTML code like this

```
<div id="city-parrent">
<input id="london" type="checkbox" value="London" name="c_city_2">
<input id="london_r" type="checkbox" value="London" name="c_city_r_2">
</div>
```

When I want to select the first check box with

```
var object_found = $("#city-parrent").find("#london");
alert(object_found.val());
```

it gives an undefined alert

When I select the second one with the same code it does not give the undefined alert

```
var object_found = $("#city-parrent").find("#london_r");
alert(object_found.val());
```

Normally this code is fine but I have this code in a for loop where this issue arises. Here is the for loop
[See the for loop]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okr2d.png)

Comment: no there is no other element with london id

Comment: can you reproduce the same here, in stack snippet?

Comment: it's working without any problem...............

Comment: also check is there any other element with same id `city-parrent`, and check value of `console.log($("#city-parrent").html())`

Comment: As @PranavCBalan said it is working fine.

Comment: Its not working in the for loop

Comment: @MariaKhan i'hv posted a working answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671374/jquery-find-not-working-with-two-ids-one-having-the-substring-of-the-other/37673530#37673530

Comment: Thanks friend I have solved it. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Loop` through the `array` and check if the element exist or not. This will prevent you from getting error. No need to `.find()` for id just use normal selector `$('#id')` because `id` will be only one there, else you will get the first one.

```
var array_cont = ['london', 'london_r']
array_cont.map(function(ac) {
    $elem = $('#' + ac);
    if ($elem.length) {
        alert($elem.val());
        $elem.attr('checked', true);
    }
})
```

```js
var array_cont = ['london', 'london_r']
array_cont.map(function(ac) {
  $elem = $('#' + ac);
  if ($elem.length) {
    alert($elem.val());
    $elem.attr('checked', true);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div id="city-parrent">
  <input id="london" type="checkbox" value="London" name="c_city_2">
  <input id="london_r" type="checkbox" value="London2" name="c_city_r_2">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

should work fine.  what version of Jquery do you have?
your version should work, sometimes, you might have to wrap it with jquery.
`$(object_found).val()`.

check this one out, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5585/

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any problem with you code: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6w19140w/)

try to enclose you code to :

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
you code is here
});
```